# How to destroy confidential data in Perl

Tags: perl

For a script that deals with private keys, symmetric encryption keys, and PINs (just to name a few), I want to destroy sensitive information as soon as it is not used any more (for example to reduce the likelihood that some core dump contains sensitive information).

Having string types in mind basically, I wrote some code that overwrites the string piece-wise, trying to optimize of 64 bit (there is no specific magic in the filler strings (except that the length is a decreasing power of two):

```perl
use constant FILLERS    => [            # fillers to overwrite memory
    "\xff\x7f\x3f\x1f\x0f\x07\x03\x01",
    "\x7e\x3c\x18\x00",
    "\xaa\x55",
    "\xc3"
];

# Burn After Use (BAU) by overwriting the string in-place,
# optionally undefining it
sub _BAU($;$)
{
    my ($obj_ref, $undef) = @_;

    if (defined($$obj_ref)) {
        my $l = length($$obj_ref);
        my ($p, $i, $f, $s);

        $p = $i = 0;
        while ($l > 0) {
            $f = FILLERS->[$i++];
            $s = length($f);
            for (; $l >= $s; $p += $s, $l -= $s) {
                substr($$obj_ref, $p, $s) = $f;
            }
        }
        undef $$obj_ref
            if ($undef);
    }
}
```

I also added a wrapper around that to process composite data structures (i.e.: `ARRAY` and `HASH`) recursively.

However there are some doubts and issues:

1. It's a bit hard to verify, but is the basic overwriting code safe (i.e.: correct)?
2. What happens if the value to overwrite is actually a number (e.g. integer)?
3. It turned out that the wrapper code fails for objects (i.e.: when they are neither `ARRAY`, nor `HASH`). I was attempting to clean the objects "from the outside"; should I modify all objects to to it "from inside", or is there a more elegant solution?

Here's the outer wrapper:

```perl
# Burn After Use (BAU), extended recursive version
sub BAU($;$$$);
sub BAU($;$$$)
{
    my ($obj_ref, $recursive, $undef, $delete) = @_;

    if ((my $ref = ref $obj_ref) eq 'SCALAR') {
        _BAU($obj_ref, $undef);
    } elsif ($ref eq 'ARRAY') {
        if ($recursive) {
            BAU(\$_, $recursive, $undef, $delete)
                foreach (@$obj_ref);
            @$obj_ref = ()
                if ($delete);
        }
        undef @$obj_ref
            if ($undef);
    } elsif ($ref eq 'HASH') {
        if ($recursive) {
            foreach (keys %$obj_ref) {
                BAU(\$obj_ref->{$_}, $recursive, $undef, $delete);
                if ($delete) {
                    delete $obj_ref->{$_};
                    _BAU(\$_, $undef);
                }
            }
        }
        undef %$obj_ref
            if ($undef);
    } elsif ($ref eq 'REF') {
        BAU($$obj_ref, $recursive, $undef, $delete)
            if ($recursive);            # else do nothing!
        undef $$obj_ref
            if ($undef);
    } else {
        croak "Unexpected reference type $ref\n"
    }
}
```

Finally here's some stupid `UNITCHECK`:

```perl
UNITCHECK {
    use Storable qw(dclone freeze thaw);
    my @test_objects = (
        qw(0 01 012 0123 01234 012345 0123456 01234567 012345678 0123456789
The_quick_brown_fox_jumps),
        [], [1], ['a1', 'a2'],
        {}, {'k' => 'v'}, {'k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2'},
        [[], [2]], [{'k' => 'v'}], ['b1', 'b2'],
        {'k' => ['c1', 'c2']}, {'K1' => {'K2' => 'joe'}});
    my @objects;

    foreach  (@objects = @{dclone(\@test_objects)}) {
        my $obj = $_;

        BAU(\$_, 1, 1, 1);
        die "BAU(1, 1, 1) failed for $_"
            if (ref($obj) eq 'SCALAR' && $obj eq $_);
    }
}
```

Suggestions for a better `UNITCHECK` are welcome, too.

Comment: It's really hard in perl to destroy all mentions of a string in memory. Due to the way the perl core does copy-on-write and uses long-lived temporary hidden variables (PADTMPs) to hold the intermediate results of string operations, bits of string could be all over the place in memory.

Comment: One way I can think of is to restart the program, saving and reloading data/states as suitable.  May be clumsy, and the program should then be written in a way to facilitate this, but the need to clear data fully is rather particular.

Answer (score 2):

1. *It's a bit hard to verify, but is the basic overwriting code safe (i.e.: correct)?*

   No.

   You only overwrite part of the buffer. Sensitive information (SI) might be found in the string buffer before the start of the string or beyond the end of the string.

   Your approach could even cause the buffer to grow, which could cause the information to be copied. This could have happened numerous times beforehand too, leaving copies of the SI in multiple places in memory.

   Also, there might be traces of the string throughout memory. For example, lexical variables actually continue to exist after they are no longer used. So a function that returns SI could be holding on to copies of it in its out-of-scope scalars.<sup>[1]</sup>
2. *What happens if the value to overwrite is actually a number (e.g. integer)?*

   You waste CPU. You don't overwrite the integer. In fact, you might make a copy of it.
3. *It turned out that the wrapper code fails for objects*

   Use `reftype` from Scalar::Util instead of `ref`.

---

Footnotes:

1. The following shows that `$x` and its string buffer continue to exist after `f` returns.

   ```perl
   use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );

   sub f { 
      my $x;
      Dump( $x );
      $x = shift . "!";
   }

   f( "foo" );
   f( "bar" );
   ```

Comment: I know garbage-collecting systems are not trivial; it almost looks as if I have to do it in C instead ;-)

Comment: Kinda like what zdim suggested, maybe you could fork a subprocess to deal with the SI?